# Android CountryCodePicker set country to null

Tags: android, mobile, country-codes, mobile-country-code

I use the **CountryCodePicker** from the [CountryCodePickerProject](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject#:%7E:text=CountryCodePickerProject) by [hbb20](https://github.com/hbb20).

I get the User's data from the DataBase, and sometimes for whatever reason the User has "" (empty string) saved as their country.

I use this Picker to edit their country, and if the User does not change his country then I get India "IN" as the `selectedCCPCountry` since the `defaultCCPCountry` automatically returns India if no country was set.

How can I set the `selectedCCPCountry` or some other flag to `null` or `""` so that in this case I can know not to change the User's data?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to check if the User's country is null or empty in the memory and if so, you'll edit the empty country to the default country, i.e. IN, right?

Comment: the User's country is always a string, either a name or just empty "".
If it's "", I want to set the country to null so when i exit the screen and save the new data, I'll know not to save anything. Currently in this case the country defaults to India.

Answer (score 0):

So I created an [issue](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/issues/496) for this on GitHub and got a quick [response](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/issues/496#issuecomment-869700181) from the [author](https://github.com/hbb20):

> It seems like your primary use case is to select country without phone
> number validation, did I get that right? if so, you should try Android
> Country Picker (https://github.com/hbb20/AndroidCountryPicker). It has out
> of box support for non selection and much more. Please let me know if that
> works for you.

Here is my response and my temporary workaround:

As I don't want to undo all the code I have already, I made a temporary workaround.
mCountryChangedByUser is false and turns true only when a country is selected inside the CountryCodePicker.

```
mCountryCCP.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCountrySelected() {
        mCountryChangedByUser = true;
        mCountryTextTV.setText(mCountryCCP.getSelectedCountryName());
        mUser.setCountry(mCountryCCP.getSelectedCountryNameCode());
    }
});
```

If the user did not change his country then just return the original country in my saveUser() function.

if (mCountryChangedByUser) {

```
    userUpdate.setCountry(mCountryCCP.getSelectedCountryNameCode() );  

} else {  
    userUpdate.setCountry(mUser.getCountry());  
}
```

Maybe next time I'll use the AndroidCountryPicker.

Thanks!